# Order of parenthesis in case of multiplication and division

Tags: c, parentheses

Consider the following statement in C

```
j=2 * 3 / 4 + 2.0 / 5 + 8 / 5;
```

If the parenthesis is done considering BODMAS rule:

```
j=(2 * (3 / 4)) + (2.0 / 5) + (8 / 5); // then j = 0
```

If we take the priority of operators in C

```
j=((2 * 3) / 4) + (2.0 / 5) + (8 / 5); // then j = 2
```

Which one is the correct order?

Comment: Both are "correct".

Comment: When this is executed in C, the results will be compiler dependent? @AllanWind

Comment: note that 2 * 3 / 4 is integer arithmetic

Comment: @AllanWind Both are _not_ correct. The second example is incorrect — because it does not follow BODMAS/PEDMAS/whatever... Operators with the same precedence are evaluated _left to right_.

Comment: j is integer type

Comment: @Dúthomhas I read the question differently.  You can write either expressions and they are "correct" (correctness depends on requirements). What op appears to mean is what which expression match the evaluation order used by c compilers so it evaluates to the same value with or without the parenthesis.  I mean, it's takes 2 seconds to try so I don't get why it's being asked really.

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, OP’s intention was what I was responding about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding BODMAS (or for Americans like me, PEMDAS). It's not a strict one at a time, in order application. Parenthesized, it groups as (B)(O)(DM)(AS). Division and multiplication are the *same* precedence (in both grade school arithmetic and the C operator precedence); similarly, addition and subtraction are the same precedence. You'll note the American acronym even flips the D and the M; it doesn't matter, because they're the same precedence, but trying to render a word with the M and D in the same space would be ugly, so we just fudge it.

Both the grade school and [C approach work from left to right when the operators are equal precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), so the correct evaluation order is:

```
j=((2 * 3) / 4) + (2.0 / 5) + (8 / 5);
```

Comment: "Both the grade school and C approach work from left to right when the operators are equal precedence, ". This helps. Thanks!

Comment: What if `j` is a float?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Maybe add this link somewhere in your answer? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @Dúthomhas: That's irrelevant to the order of operations question. `j` isn't involved in the calculation, and the thing being assigned to is only a factor *after* the value is computed. The actual value computed is (extremely close to) `2.4`; if `j` is an integer type, it'll get reduced to `2`, if it's a floating point type, it'll be roughly `2.4`.

Comment: It is relevant to the comment `// then j = 2`.

Comment: @AllanWind: Sure. I suppose the OP didn't understand the left-to-right rule, so that's useful info they didn't have.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: Ah, that's just a copy from the OP. Deleted; it's not necessary.

Comment: ...which makes it relevant to the answer, methinks. I already upvoted your answer, BTW, and it is fine as it stands. I just like to future-proof the answer for any poor soul trying to figure out why he/she is getting 2.4 by declaring `double j` or something. But... that’s my take. Feel free to ignore me. I’ll be ok. `:-)`